# Multiple files with with different Columns using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a large number of Excel files with different Columns

For Example:

**File 1:**

```
Name | sale | Tips
-------------
sam  |  9   | 7
cham |  2   | 2
```

**File 2:**

```
Name | sale | Items
-------------------
mini |  6    | Tshirt
Lary |  3    | Hat
```

**Output:**

```
Name |  sale | Items
--------------------
sam  |  9    | Nan
cham |  2    | Nan
mini |  6    | Tshirt
Lary |  3    | Hat
```

I have 500 files to create into one data Set

This code is working to an extent, But unless all the columns are the same.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob,os
import numpy as np


inputFile = 'C:/Users/Desktop/test'

all_workbooks =glob.glob(os.path.join(inputFile,'*.xlsx'))

column_list = []
for files in all_workbooks:
    
    data= pd.read_excel(files,header =0,sheet_name='sheet1')
    column_list.append(data)
    stack_np = np.vstack(column_list)
    newData = pd.DataFrame(stack_np,columns=['Name','Sale'])

print(newData)
```

This code works if I have the same columns in all the files.

Can anyone help me with a solution, if I have unordered columns?

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect the dataframes and concatenate them at after the loop

```
all_dfs =[]
wanted_columns = ['Name', 'sale', 'Items']
for files in all_workbooks:
    data = pd.read_excel(files,header =0,sheet_name='sheet1')
    data = data[wanted_columns] # or skip this line to use all columns
    all_dfs.append(data)

master_df = pd.concat(all_dfs)
del all_dfs, data
```